# google trip planner auto-fill

Tags: google-maps-api-3, transit

We are currently using the google trip planning feature on our transit website. The issue we are running into is the fact that when a customer types in a starting point (for example "Queensway" in Kelowna, BC Canada) we get auto-fill results from all over North America. Can the auto-fill results be restricted to a specific province or state? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [*Component Filtering*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=cs#ComponentFiltering)

> In a geocoding response, the Google Maps Geocoding API can return address results restricted to a specific area. The restriction is specified using the **`components`** filter. A filter consists of a list of **`component:value`** pairs separated by a pipe (`|`). Only the results that match all the filters will be returned. Filter values support the same methods of spelling correction and partial matching as other geocoding requests. If a geocoding result is a partial match for a component filter it will contain a **`partial_match`** field in the response.

The components that can be filtered include:

- **`route`** matches long or short name of a route.
- **`locality`** matches against both **`locality`** and **`sublocality`** types.
- **`administrative_area`** matches all the **`administrative_area`** levels.
- **`postal_code`** matches **`postal_code`** and **`postal_code_prefix`**.
- **`country`** matches a country name or a two letter [ISO 3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) country code.

> Note: Each address component can only be specified either in the address parameter or as a component filter, but not both. Doing so may result in **`ZERO_RESULTS`**.
>
> A geocode for "Santa Cruz" with **`components=country:ES`** will return Santa Cruz de Tenerife in Canary Islands, Spain. Request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=santa+cruz&components=country:ES&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

See this sample: [Place Autocomplete Hotel Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch) for code implementation.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! This does help.